# Get default instance from protobuf descriptor

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How can I get the default instance of a protobuf message, if I only know its descriptor:

```
Descriptor descriptor   = SomeOuterMessage.getDescriptor()
                              .findNestedTypeByName("InnerMessageName");
Message defaultInstance = descriptor. <???> // how do I get an instance of "InnerMessageName"?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the default instance through the [`DynamicMessage`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage) class.

Say for a proto like following:

```
Message PhoneBook {
    repeated Person people = 1;
}
Message Person {
    required Name name = 1;
    optional String phone = 2;
}
Message Name {
    required String family_name = 1;
    required String given_name = 2;
}
```

The code for getting the default instance for `People` would be something like:

```
PhoneBook phoneBook = phoneBook.getDefaultInstance();
Descriptors.Descriptor personDescriptor = phoneBook.getDescriptor().findNestedTypeByName("people");
DynamicMessage defaultPeopleInstance = DynamicMessage.newBuilder(personDescriptor).getDefaultInstanceForType().build();
assert defaultPeopleInstance == People.getDefaultInstance();
```